# What does printf returns if not called as function?

Tags: c, printf

This code works fine after commenting statement one. Statement two gives some garbage value but at least it runs. I'm not getting how does the printf in argument gives a value if it's not called as a function?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int printf = 123;    // statement one
    printf ("%d", printf); // statement two  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler warning should give a clue: "*warning: format ‘%d’ expects type `int`, but argument 2 has type `int (*)(const char * __restrict__)`*". i.e. `printf` is the pointer that points to `printf ()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function name without parentheses doesn't return a value - it evaluates to the *address* of the function (i. e. it is a function pointer of type `size_t (*)(const char *, ...)`). Essentially, this is the address where the CPU will jump among the instructions whenever it encounters a call to `printf()`.

By the way, if I recall correctly, assigning to a function's name is undefined behavior, so is printing a pointer using the `%d` format specifier - you should use

```
printf("%p", (void *)printf);
```

Also, you *can* declare function pointers, assign them the address of another function and call them just fine:

```
size_t (*my_printf)(const char *, ...) = printf;
my_printf("This actually called printf!\n");

printf("my_printf: %p\n", (void *)my_printf);
printf("original printf: %p\n", (void *)printf);
```

The last two statements print the same address.

**Edit:** Strictly speaking, even the above "solution" is nonstandard as the Standard doesn't guarantee that function pointers can be cast to data pointer types. That means basically that there's no way for print the address of a function, however, on most systems, casting to `void *` *apparently* works.

Comment: Hehe, somebody upvoted me, then realized it was me, then revoked the upvote :D

Comment: "*assigning to a function's name is undefined behavior*" - Where is the function name being assigned to?

Comment: @ArjunShankar `int printf = 123`, maybe? I'm not sure if there can be  a function and a variable with the same name, but I suspect not really.

Comment: If you don't comment that statement, the program won't even compile. Because `int printf` masks the `stdio.h` declaration of `printf`. The error I get on 'statement two' is: "*error: called object ‘printf’ is not a function*".

Comment: @ArjunShankar That's what I'm just saying. Basically OP's question is broken in its current form.

Comment: All I was saying was: In the OP's question, a function isn't being assigned to. But an integer is being 'called' (which of course is a weird thing to do).

Comment: @ArjunShankar Right, but that doesn't compile either. `#include <stdio.h>` and `int printf = 123;` don't go well with each other.

Comment: One of us is missing the point. Anyway, between the answers and comments, I guess all grey areas have been covered. So.. cheers!

Comment: @ArjunShankar OK, let us not continue this discussion.

Comment: I couldn't resist: http://codepad.org/kLXTL32Q Although, I *will* shut up now :) (`gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99`)

Comment: @H2CO3 It is perfectly legal to have a *local* variable named `printf`. However it's not legal to have a global variable (or function) named `printf` (unless it's static) because global names need to be unique.

Comment: @sepp2k You too. Yes, it's just strange. And I believe it's not necessarly the best practice doing so... :P

Answer (score 3):

In statement 2, when the identifier `printf` is passed to the function, it is a *function pointer* - a pointer to the function `printf` - and the *garbage value* is the result of trying to print this address using `printf` and the format: `%d`: you should see a compiler warning when printing a pointer using `%d`.

Comment: This answer is still causing UB. Since `printf("%p")` takes a `void *` argument, passing in a `size_t (*)(const char *, ...)` invokes undefined bahvior if you don't do a cast to void pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 are you sure? remember that function pointers are different than data pointers. At any rate, I removed the language about `%p` altogether.

Comment: @H2CO3 You shoudn't be so sure. you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579835/c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer) useful. A search will bring up even more.

Comment: so it's even worse than that of I knew. In this case, there's no way to print the address of a function.