# get function member address

Tags: c++, function, structure, member

Is there any way to get the exact address of a function member?
For example I have :

```
struct foo
{
    void print() { printf("bla bla bla"); }
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
unsigned int address = foo::print;
```

Comment: Depending on how you are going to use the pointer, consider looking into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: *"unsigned int address"* - No, not at all.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to declare the pointer to the member function:

```
typedef void (foo::*address)();
address func = &foo::print;
```

In order to call non-static member function you will need an existing instance of that class:

```
(fooInstance.*func)();
```

Comment: Thanks, but **foo::print** -> **void* address** - Is this possible?

Comment: @xersi read about [function pointers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) and take the advice of  Joachim Pileborg about `std::function` and `std::bind`.

Comment: @xersi no.`void*` is a data pointer type. Your member function pointer is a code-pointer type. There are, hard as it is to imagine, platforms where they size and/or encodings of the pointer types are different (I can think of two right off the cuff, both from IBM). I suggest you become familiar with [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579835/c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer). Then when you think you need to store a function pointer in a `void*`, *don't*.

Comment: @xersi: member function pointers are almost always larger than 'regular' function or data pointers.  So no - you can't store a member function pointer in a `void*`, even with casting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "exact address".  There's
certainly no way of putting any address in an `unsigned int`
(which is smaller than a pointer on my machine).  For that
matter, there's no way of putting a pointer to a function in
a `void*`.  Again, I've used machines where pointers to
a function were larger than `void*`.  And finally, there's no
way of putting a pointer to (non-static) member function into
a pointer to function; pointer to member functions are almost
always larger.  Finally, given:

```
void (MyClass::*pmf)();
MyClass* p;
(p->*pmf)();
```

mais call different functions, depending on the contents of `p`.

So it's not at all clear what you're asking for.