# Why do function pointers all have the same value?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

For example:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

void funcOne() {
}

void funcTwo( int x ) {
}

int main() {

  void (*ptrOne)() = funcOne;
  cout << ptrOne << endl;      //prints 1

  void (*ptrTwo)( int x ) = funcTwo;
  cout << ptrTwo << endl;      //prints 1

  int (*ptrMain)() = main;
  cout << ptrMain << endl;     //prints 1

}
```

Does anyone know the reasoning behind this? At first I thought it was because the functions don't exist in memory since I never call on them, and thus they never get added to the stack.  But even the value of a pointer to the main function prints out 1.

Comment: It doesn't for me. On MSV2012 I get: 011A1230, 011A122B, 011A12F3 for each print.

Comment: Those statements should print function pointer addresses

Comment: @Borgleader Oh, what does it print out for you ? Maybe this is just specific to my compiler or something like that.

Comment: @billz: Why? Does `cout << ...` handle arguments of type pointer-to-function?

Comment: @billz My print statements are printing out the values of the pointers which are the memory addresses of the functions.

Comment: @KeithThompson you are right. MS compiler prints out correctly which distracted me.

Comment: @Borgleader thank for letting me know it's something specific to the environment I'm running on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function pointers do not implicitly convert to `void *`, which is what `operator <<` overloads on.

This is specified by omission in C++11 §4.10/2:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” **where T is an object type,** can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The result of converting a “pointer to cv T” to a “pointer to cv void” points to the start of the storage location where the object of type T resides, as if the object is a most derived object (1.8) of type T (that is, not a base class subobject). The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

Function types are not object types.

Moreover, you can't even do it using `static_cast`. Functions and objects may live in completely different address spaces (this is called Harvard architecture), with differently-sized pointers. Converting a function pointer to `void *` can *maybe* be done with `reinterpret_cast`: it's "conditionally-supported" (C++11 §5.2.10/8). Such a `void *` should only be used for printing or conversion back to the original function pointer type.

Comment: Thank you!
So the problem is function pointers don't convert to void pointers.
Does this mean that all the other types of pointers do implicitly convert when used with the << operator?

Comment: Actually, after reading that out loud a couple times, I totally understand.  
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this, or it will be converted to a `bool` type.

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptrOne) << endl;
```

Comment: Why would it be converted to a bool type?

Comment: It may, not will because it prints fine when using MSVC2012.

Comment: Okay so I at least know this is something specific to the environment I'm running on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading in C++ adds all sorts of nasty complexities. (It lets you do awesome stuff too—but sometimes it's just a headache.)

As explained in the other answers, C++ is doing some automatic type coercion on your function pointers. If you just use the good ol' C-style `printf` you should get the results you're expecting:

```
#include <cstdio>

// ...

printf("func1: %p\nfunc2: %p\n", funcOne, funcTwo);
```

Comment: Technically, this could be a type error, since `%p` expects `void *`, so you will have to cast.  On most implementations it won't make a difference, but that doesn't change the fact that it's a type error.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - That's an interesting point. The contract _does_ state that it expects a `void *`, but since it's a varargs function the cast should just get thrown away anyway. I think a lot of modern compilers will actually parse the format string and do some extra checks for you—but that's above and beyond anything the C standard could actually specify. I'll give you a +1 for making an interesting point, but I'm not going to add extra casts that the compiler should be ignoring if it's adhering to the C standard.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Actually, according to [an answer to another question about function pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5579907/1427124), the C standard doesn't even allow you to cast a function pointer to the `void *` type. Potatoswatter's answer seems to say that this is the case in the C++ standard as well.

Comment: Hey DaoWen, I tried that and it says funcOne and funcTwo weren't declared in the scope.  Did you mean to put ptrOne and ptrTwo in the function parameters instead?

Comment: @KacyRaye - Yes, it should work if you do that. Maybe that's why  Dietrich Epp was talking about the code having a type error... However, the code that I worked works fine with my version of g++.

Comment: Okay thanks, it did work when I changed it. I've never actually used printf before ( I just started C++ two weeks ago ) so you actually forced to me to go look up what all that Japanese meant haha. Now I'm aware of another option at my disposal :) +1 point !

Comment: @KacyRaye - I studied Japanese all the way through high school and I'd say it's actually easier to read than the more obscure options of POSIX format strings!

Comment: @DaoWen: The cast for a varargs function does not get "thrown away".  The type of the argument determines its implementation-dependent representation.  So, for example, if a function pointer were two words long but a `void*` were one word long then you might end up with serious garbage on the other end.  And while you're right that the standard doesn't allow the `void*` conversion, it also doesn't allow `printf()` of function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
void (*ptrOne)() = funcOne;
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptrOne) << endl;

void (*ptrTwo)( int x ) = funcTwo;
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptrTwo) << endl;

int (*ptrMain)() = main;
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptrMain) << endl;
```

I think normally, function overloading rules mean that the version of `<<` being called is `operator<<(bool)`, which means:

```
cout << ptrOne << endl;
```

Gets transformed into:

```
cout << (ptrOne != NULL) << endl;
```

Which is the same as:

```
cout << true << endl;
```

Comment: Mind explaining what that does?

Comment: What do you want me to explain?

Comment: reinterpret_cast<void*> 
I've never seen/heard of that before.

Comment: It should be covered in any C++ reference.  I hate to put it this way, but that's a really basic question.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reinterpret_cast