# Why do I get garbage values from a structure initialized from void**

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, data-structures

I test this code:

```
void foo (void* data[])
{
    static struct structure
    {
        char character;
        int  integer;
    } st1 = *((struct structure *)data);

    printf("[%i][%c]", st1.integer, st1.character);
}

int main (void)
{
    void* *data = calloc(2, sizeof(void* ));
    char  arg1 = 'b';
    int   arg2 = 20;

    data[0] = (char* )&arg1;
    data[1] = (int* ) &arg2;

    foo(data);

    return(0);
}
```

but I get garbage values instead of the intended

> [20] [b]

---

I have tried many things, including st1 = `*((struct structure *)&data);`, (despite that AFAIK `data` is already an address) declaring and initializing separate structure pointer and then deref-ing it, but nothing works.

What could be the reason this happens and how should I do it properly approaching the same idea of obtaining function arguments ?

Comment: This smells like UB to me, but you mixed the order of the parameters regardless.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm sorry, It seems to be the post-writing's fault, since I don't nor I can't copy/paste. The original code had proper orders. The problem stays.

Comment: When I see a void pointer I think - what is a person thinking - The design and coding is wrong. Very wrong. Fix the design and code to not use void

Comment: @EdHeal I found it for convenient, so I have no intentions to redesign everything.

Comment: Pray tell - What is convenient in a datatype that you have lost the semantics of.

Comment: Your code is undefined on several levels. There is no sensible way to 'fix' this.

Comment: PS: When you are casting variables you are usually doing something wrong

Comment: @EdHeal void pointers are intended to be type-casted. Otherwise they are pretty useless.

Comment: When you require a void pointer you are doing something wrong

Comment: @EdHeal is that written in standards or is it your own thought ?

Comment: Experience tells me that void pointers are a bad idea. My experience tells me that you should not use them. It also tells me that void pointers end up with a question on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @EdHeal They are a bad idea but sometimes they are the only idea.

Comment: Please explain the motivation to use them here

Comment: @EdHeal Why would I do it? I am not the only one who find the way to use them. Everyone have their own preferences and places to put it to use. Mine happens to be too broad to explain and I don't see a reason to

Comment: 1. Type - You tell the developer and the compiler that nature of the object. 2. void pointers throws that away. 3. You try to recover the info but this is a guess by the compiler. 4. You end up writing questions on stafckoverflow why things do not work. 5. use the compiler and the type system - it will save a lot of bother for you

Comment: @EdHeal I am working on a game engine that enables C coding by virtue of C interpreter. So I cannot do typeof or any other luxory of modern compilers

Comment: `void*` is to be used when the type cannot be assumed, nor does it matter. Your code *wants* to assume, and it matters a great deal to it.

Comment: The only times I have to use a void pointer is for a faced. That is twice in my life. Otherwise use a type.

Comment: @EdHeal Well, I am glad you needed not to use void*.

Comment: Do you need to use a void pointer. Please justify the need

Comment: @EdHeal I am giving an array of function pointers to a function. Along that array of function pointers there is a corresponding array of lists (arrays) of void pointers to give them as arguments to the functions.

Comment: You should give *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579835/c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer)* a read if you intend to cast function pointers to `void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally and portably can't expect your struct to be the same size as two `void*`.

You can't expect any specific padding inside the struct itself. And you can't expect that casting a `char` to `void*` will produce the same valid `char` back when the memory region is reinterpreted as part of a struct.

The behavior of (the code I think I read) is as undefined as it can get.

---

I originally completely overlooked the fact that you assign addresses to the two `void*` (imagined you cast the `char` and `int` themselves to `void*`), so your reinterpretation of those values need to not result in what you expect at all. In fact, it may result in trap values. So your code *is* undefiend behavior.

Comment: The size of the structure is 8 bytes, the size of void** is 12 bytes. Two void*'s would be 24

Comment: @Malina - Besides the fact your calculation is wrong, you can't expect any specific `sizeof` for any data type except `char`. You assumptions need not hold, making your code undefined.

Comment: I am just telling you the results from the sizeof. I haven't done any calculations. Can you please tell me the correct way I do it? So that I can finish using stack overflow for "too broad questions"

Comment: `sizeof(void**) == 2` doesn't imply `2 * sizeof(void*) == 24`. The two types need no be the same size. And even if those *are* the results. Do you not see a problem with your structure falling completely inside the first 8 bytes of the memory you passed?

Comment: @Malina - The correct way is to avoid this heap of undefined behavior. Don't handle raw memory in anything other than `unsigned char*`. Use `memcpy` or `memove` and actually take your medicine and remove that hackery from your code base.

Comment: If I can do: `unsigned char byte_val = *((char* )&integer);` I don't see why I couldn't do that with the struct.

Comment: @Malina - The C standard *requires* that using char types will work. It makes no such requirements about structs.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly.. does this mean I can't do `short shortv = *((short* )&integer);` or is it specifically structs that cannot receive such type casting ?

Comment: Also, Omar's approach actually worked, why wouldn't that be the correct way ?

Comment: @Malina - reinterpreting like that (except with chars) is specifically named by the standard as undefined behavior. Only chars are exempt in most cases (since they are how you'd manipulate raw bytes). The fact that Omar's approach works is another facet of undefined behavior. It may "work". It's not guaranteed to always work, A simple compiler update can break your code, and it won't be a bug in the compiler that you can complain about.

Comment: Okay that covers it all up. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is located in your structure itself.

In your `data`, in main, you wrote an `int*` and a `char*`. However, in your function, you define the struct as it contains a `char` and `int`, what you should write is :

```
void foo (void* data[])
{
    static struct structure
    {
        char* character;
        int*  integer;
    } st1 = *((struct structure *)data);

    printf("[%i][%c]", *(st1.integer), *(st1.character));
}
```