# Function returning 32 bit address when I am wanting 64 bit

Tags: c, pointers, assembly

I am playing with a library for reflective DLL loading. Here is the file I am having issues with:

https://github.com/stephenfewer/ReflectiveDLLInjection/blob/master/inject/src/GetProcAddressR.c

On the last line:

```
return fpResult;
```

It contains the correct full length address of the function I am trying to get the address to.

When I go back to my main program which looks like this:

```
PVOID address = GetProcAddressR(buffer, length);
```

The address gets truncated to a 32 bit number.

```
0x00002023A83EFF30
```

turns into

```
0xFFFFFFFA83EFF30
```

I check the disasemmbly of this and it looks like the instruction

```
CDQE
```

Is being called which is doing exactly the issue I am having. However, I am not sure where in the file linked above is causing any of that.

Comment: How do you know that it gets truncated?

Comment: In Visual Studio I can see that ProcAddressR return the full address. But then address gets turned into 0xffffffffA83EFF30

Comment: What's the return type? In the linked code I only see `FARPROC WINAPI` neither of which should specify the type. So what is it? EDIT: ah apparently `FARPROC` means `int` return type. There is your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579835/c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer. You're assigning a function pointer to a `void*`.

Comment: I have tried to use PVOID and I get a similar outcome. Instead of the address being 0xFFFFFFFA83EFF30 to 0x00000000A83EFF30

Comment: Have you changed **all** occurrences of `FARPTR`? There are a couple in the code.

Comment: Yes, 4 occurrences in the file all changed to PVOID.

Comment: Function pointers should not be assigned to void pointers, according to the C spec.

Comment: I created a function pointer such as PVOID (*pf)(CALLBACKPROC) and that also did not work.

Comment: As in `pf address = GetProcAddressR(buffer, length);`?

Comment: typedef PVOID(*pf) (CALLBACKPROC) and address = GetProcAddressR(buffer, length);

Comment: @meat: all the mainstream x86-64 compilers (gcc/clang/msvc/ICC) are fine casting function pointers to/from `void*`.  Both types have the same width in the mainstream x86-64 ABIs, and x86 being a von Neumann architecture has no reason to munge data when casting between data vs. code pointers, so for simplicity and sanity compilers don't do anything weird.  The sign-extension of the return value from 32 to 64 bit proves that the compiler is for some reason treating the return value as a 32-bit `int`, not any kind of pointer.  Like if you omitted a declaration entirely. (implicit declaration=int)

Comment: @Doritos You'll need to change FARPROC in the header file too. However the entire GetProcAddressR.c file have a lot of casts and nasty stuff to 32 bit integers, it doesn't look like it's meant for 64 bit targets at all.

Comment: What if you change all occurrences of `UINT_PTR` by `LPBYTE`?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled about this due to my own failure, maybe this helps someone at some point who's just blindsided at some point like I was.
In my case I have just forgot to include the header that actually declares the datatype I have tried to use.
In bellow example the application just built fine in VS2022 but didn't report any error or warning. While the issue would appear in main(), the variable sample has been assigned a 32b value of the 64b pointer actually returned by sample_create().
From technical/compiler point of view that's totally fine for me, I was just missing a warning by VS that there's an unknown type used.

See following simplified example.

sample.h:

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_H_
#define SAMPLE_H_
struct sample_s {
    int a;
    int b;
};
struct sample_s *sample_create(void);
#endif
```

sample.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sample.h"
struct sample_s *sample_create(void) {
    struct sample_s *sample;
    sample = malloc(sizeof(struct sample_s));
    if(!sample)
        return NULL;

    return sample;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
/** No include of sample.h caused the issue on my side */

int main() {
    struct sample_s *sample;
    sample = sample_create();
    free(sample);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good compilers should warn about implicit declarations defaulting to an `int` return type in this case, but yes it will compile without actually erroring.  (Unless you use `-Werror` to promote warnings to errors.)  https://godbolt.org/z/Tvzc7raGa shows GCC warning even without `-Wall`, but MSVC only warning `<source>(3): warning C4047: 'return': 'void *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'`, not about the call itself.  And MSVC `-Wall` is often unusably verbose, and their standard headers generate tons of warnings.