# how to run some method that will run on different thread every 2 seconds?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I want to write some code that on the main it will start some thread that will run every 2 seconds and will print something on the console.

the start function need to be something like this

```
     void StartTask(void* methodRoRun, long repeatTimeInSeconds);
```

that mean that the method receive pointer to function (methodRoRun) that will run every repeatTimeInSeconds seconds.

I can't find how to do it in C++

Comment: Can you be more specific about what help you need? Do you know how to create a thread?

Comment: Break your desires into steps and focus on one step at a time. It looks like you want to know how to create a thread, how to make and use a timer, how to callback on a timer, how to pass around function pointers to threads, and maybe more. That's alot to cover for one post.

Comment: Does `repeatTimeInSeconds` include time used by `methodRoRun` ?

Comment: Your interface is so old. how about `void StartTask(std::function<void()> f, std::chrono::seconds repeatTime);` ?

Comment: [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is arguably the easiest way to safely manage asynchronous tasks. However, you'll still need a good understanding of synchronizations and how to avoid race conditions.

Comment: You can't safely assign a function pointer to `void*`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579907/7359094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

void f() {
    printf("Task started\n");
    // do stuff
}

void StartTask(std::function<void()> methodRoRun, long repeatTimeInSeconds) {
    std::thread th([methodRoRun, repeatTimeInSeconds]() {
        while (true ) {
            methodRoRun();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(repeatTimeInSeconds));
        }
    });
    th.detach();
}

int main() {
    StartTask([](){ f(); }, 1);

    while (true) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

People are correctly pointing out this that detaching threads and having endless loops is not good practice, but the example just illustrates the approach.

Comment: `while(true) {}` is, strictly speaking, undefined behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x

Comment: Or just return the thread and then join it in main. Then change the condition to `while(running)` or something.

Comment: In practice, detaching a thread is rarely what you want to do. It works when the scope of the program is limited, which includes short examples, but for real applications it's rarely practical.

Comment: and if i want to add parameters to this function that will called each X seconds - how to do it ?

Comment: `[](){ f(); }` can simply be `&f`.

Comment: @fran it is UB unless the code within it does IO, like printing, or a few other operations.