# How to make a dynamic while loop program in C?

Tags: c

How to make a dynamic while loop program in C?

Because of this:

```
if {
    while
} else if {
    while
} else {
    while
}
```

I want to make a program doing dynamic while loop. I did two approaches.

first: (not work)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define aaa printf("0\n")

int main() {

    int x = 1, i = 1;

    if (x == 1) {
        #undef aaa
        #define aaa printf("1\n")
    }   else {
        #undef aaa
        #define aaa printf("2\n")
    }

    while (i <= 10) {
        aaa;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

second: (works)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*FunctionName)();

void fun1();
void fun2();

int main() {

    int x = 1, i = 1;
    FunctionName y;

    y = (x == 1) ? fun1 : fun2;

    while (i <= 10) {
        y();
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void fun1() {
    printf("1\n");
}

void fun2() {
    printf("2\n");
}
```

but, it can only accept same type of functions. in this case, the y().
it can't accept two or more types of functions at the same time.
for example: f1(a) and f2(a,b).
so, I have to make all functions to same type because it can't accept diff types.

this dynamic while loop program can only accept one type of functions.
then it is not full dynamic.
how can I solve the problem? how can I make it accept all kinds of functions?
any comments are welcome. thanks.

Comment: Lines starting with `#` are preprocessor directives. Preprocessors don't know what `if` statements are.

Comment: I think it is bad practice to write programs using such a construct. If there is one.

Comment: This smells a bit like XY-problem. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can just run different functions with an if inside the while.

Comment: Although not in standard C, but in POSIX, a `void *` can hold any function pointer you want. Your problem will be how to know which cast you need to use the function that it holds.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I am not aware of POSIX defining C language extensions; but anyway in standard C it is not UB to cast back and forth a function pointer as long as you end up with the original one. So you can store them with a tag and carry them around in an opaque pointer type.

Comment: I actually have some functions with almost same while loop.
I want to combine these functions into one. then I can get rid of duplicated codes.

Comment: @Acorn https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579907/6872717

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Yes, I explicitly said function pointers (not to/from plain ones), which is how you would do it in a portable way. The C standard mentions as a common extension (J.5.7) casting function pointers from/to `void *`. Checking that answer (thanks!), indeed POSIX seems to explicitly require such an extension to work to be conforming (although from the changelog section it looks like an oversight; they probably couldn't hope to change the return type or the C standard, so they went that route). Not sure if the J.5.7 bit was added *after* POSIX "fixed" that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but you could sort of make it work by sending the arguments with a void pointer.

```
typedef void (*FunctionName)(void *);
```

Then (if you want several parameters) create different structs for different functions:

```
struct fooArgs {
    int x;
    double y;
    char *s;
};
```

Then create a function like this:

```
void foo(void *args) {
    struct fooArgs *a = (struct fooArgs*)args;
    int x = a->x;
    double y = a->y;
    char *s = a->s;
    /* Do stuff */
}
```

You need to write something similar to `y = (x == 1) ? fun1 : fun2;` for the arguments. It could look something like this:

```
void *args;

struct fooArgs a = { 5, 6.7, NULL };

if(x == 1) {
    y = foo;
    args = a;
} else if (x == 2) {
    y = bar;
    args = NULL; // For a function without arguments;
}  

while (i <= 10) {
    y(args);
    i++;
}
```

However, I don't recommend doing this unless you are really sure about what you are doing. If it is for performance, the gain is likely very low, and it's even likely that you just make it difficult for the compiler optimizer with worse performance as a result. Use things like this for performance as an absolute last resort, and only if you really need those extra milliseconds.

Comment: thanks. This looks like the answer I am looking for.
I think I need a little time to study and see if it can be used. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> but, it can only accept same type of functions. in this case, the y(). it can't accept two or more types of functions at the same time. for example: f1(a) and f2(a,b). so, I have to make all functions to same type because it can't accept diff types.

Yes, because otherwise, what would be the arguments? In other words your `fun1` and `fun2` take no parameters. If you want to call a `fun3` that takes 1 parameter, what would be the argument?

In other words, consider:

```
void fun3(int);

y = fun3;
y(???);
```

For some values of `y`, you would have to pass different number of arguments. Same for the return type.

What you would have to do is to create a wrapper function that does what is called a *partial application* of e.g. `fun3`:

```
void g() {
    fun3(42);
}

y = g;
y();
```

Here, `g` has the responsibility of knowing what the arguments of `fun3` are (they may be constant as in this example, or come from somewhere else).

In languages that support user-defined types (and maybe OOP), like C++, a typical solution is to create a *"Callable"* object that stores the arguments as data members and can be called as if it was a function.

Further, in some of those languages, you get some syntax sugar to easily create those Callable objects in-place, typically called lambdas or closures.

Answer (score 1):

put switch or if else for more complicated conditions inside the while loop:

```
while(i <= 10)
{
   if(condition 1)
      //call f1();
   ...
   else if (condition n)
   {
      // call fn;
   ...
   else
   {
      // nothing of the prevous cases
   }
   i ++
}
```

you can also use `swithch case` inside the while loop if you are comparing against constants...
hope it helps

Comment: thanks. I did this before.
but, I just don't want the loop running if else every time.
so I use if while else while. and then I found i got so many duplicated codes.

Comment: @Frank If you care about performance, duplicate the code and check if it is faster. If you don't care, just use this solution. The madness involved in getting a performant solution with function pointers is not worth it.  Let the compiler do its job optimizing by using -O3.