# convert member function to pointer to member function

Tags: c++, templates

Clang,GCC,MSVC have different opinion about conversion of member functions.
Who is right ?

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QNsgwd

```
template<typename T>
struct a
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void va(Args...) {}

    template <typename X>
    void x(X) {}

    void y(int) {}
};

struct b : a<b>
{
    void testva()
    {
        using F = void (a<b>::*)();

        F f = (F)&a<b>::va<int>; // gcc: error, msvc: error, clang: ok
    }

    void testx()
    {
        using F = void (a<b>::*)();

        F f = (F)&a<b>::x<int>;// gcc: error, msvc: ok, clang: ok
    }

    void testy()
    {
        using F = void (a<b>::*)();

        F f = (F)& a<b>::y; // gcc: ok, msvc: ok, clang: ok
    }
};
```

Comment: Include the compiler errors in your question.

Comment: Cannot convert functions. Do you mean full log from gcc.godbolt?

Comment: It doesn't need to be the full log, but include the error message (and the following informational lines) for the compiler errors.

Comment: `F` is a pointer to a member function that takes no parameters. `va<int>` takes one parameter.  So does `X<int>`. Since when does a pointer to a function that takes one parameter can be converted to a pointer to another function that take no parameters, whether they are regular functions or class methods? That conversion should not work. `y` also takes one `int` parameter. That conversion should not work either. But what about having an explicit cast in there...

Comment: Why shouldn't it  be a UB? I'm also interested if it is legal to convert function with argument to function without one.  Also will look for the answer)

Comment: C11 standard, 6.3.2.3 §8: : A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579907/558098

Answer (score 3):

`testx` and `testy` are well-formed, so gcc is wrong about `testx`. But the Standard is somewhat vague about `testva`.

Starting with the easiest, in `testy` the expression `&a<b>::y` names a non-template function which is not overloaded, so it has type `void (a<b>::*)(int)` without need for further analysis. Conversion from any pointer-to-member-function to any other pointer-to-member-function is a well-formed `reinterpret_cast` with unspecified results except if converted back to the original type, and a C-style cast can do what a `reinterpret_cast` can do.

For template functions we have [[over.over]/1-2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over):

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. A function template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts. A function with type `F` is selected for the function type `FT` of the target type required in the context if `F` (after possibly applying the function pointer conversion) is identical to `FT`.  The target can be
>
> - ...
> - an explicit type conversion ([expr.type.conv], [expr.static.cast], [expr.cast]),
> - ...
>
> If the name is a function template, template argument deduction is done ([temp.deduct.funcaddr]), and if the argument deduction succeeds, the resulting template argument list is used to generate a single function template specialization, which is added to the set of overloaded functions considered. [ *Note:* As described in [temp.arg.explicit], if deduction fails and the function template name is followed by an explicit template argument list, the *template-id* is then examined to see whether it identifies a single function template specialization. If it does, the *template-id* is considered to be an lvalue for that function template specialization. The target type is not used in that determination. — *end note* ]

So this means we first try template argument deduction for `a<b>::x<int>`, matching it to the target type `void (a<b>::*)()`. But there are no specializations that can possibly give an exact match, since they all have one argument, not zero, so deduction fails. But per the note, there's also [temp.arg.explicit] (paragraph 3 in C++17, [4 in the latest C++20 draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#4)):

> Trailing template arguments that can be deduced or obtained from default template-arguments may be omitted from the list of explicit template-arguments. A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) not otherwise deduced will be deduced as an empty sequence of template arguments. ... In contexts where deduction is done and fails, or in contexts where deduction is not done, if a template argument list is specified and it, along with any default template arguments, identifies a single function template specialization, then the *template-id* is an lvalue for the function template specialization.

In `testx`, the *template-id* `a<b>::x<int>` identifies a single function template specialization. So it names that specialization, and again the C-style cast is valid with unspecified result.

So in `testva`, does `a<b>::va<int>` identify a single specialization? It would certainly be possible to use that expression to name different specializations, via [[temp.arg.explicit]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#9):

> Template argument deduction can extend the sequence of template arguments corresponding to a template parameter pack, even when the sequence contains explicitly specified template arguments.

Except this says "template argument deduction". And here the template argument deduction involved fails, since it required an impossible match with the target type `void (a<b>::*)()`. So nothing really explains whether `a<b>::va<int>` identifies a single specialization, since no other method of getting additional template arguments is described, or identifies multiple specializations, since it could be validly used in other contexts with matching target types.

Comment: @YSC Oops, good catch. Though possibly there's other wording saying `template <class X, class Y> void f(X, Y); int g(void (*)(int, int)); int a = g(f<int>);` should work?

Comment: I'm puzzled. If your interpretation is right, would https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YNczD2 be valid?

Comment: @YSC Though I guess the Note wouldn't make sense if [over.over]/1-2 doesn't also apply to a _template-id_. I'm undecided on the `va` case, and that example has essentially the same questions. Interesting that gcc and msvc switched to allowing it, though.

Answer (score 0):

### clang is right

> #### [`[expr.reinterpret.cast]/10`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#10)
>
> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `X` of type `T1`” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to member of `Y` of type `T2`” if `T1` and `T2` are both function types or both object types. The null member pointer value is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type. The result of this conversion is unspecified, except in the following cases:
>
> - Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a different pointer-to-member-function type and back to its original type yields the original pointer-to-member value.
> - Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to data member of `X` of type `T1`” to the type “pointer to data member of `Y` of type `T2`” (where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer-to-member value.

`&a<b>::va<int>` *et al.* are *prvalue* of type "pointer to member of `a<b>` of type `void(int)`" and converting it (without calling the resulting function pointer whose value is unspecified) is legal.

Comment: That clause describes `reinterpret_cast`. I see no `reinterpret_cast` in the question.

Comment: @Sam since no other cast is valid, `(F) ` defaults to a reinterpret cast.

Comment: _"since no other cast is valid"_ IMO a complete answer would start by proving this. Perhaps that's where the discrepancy lies

Comment: @Light I was still at the office 10min ago ;)

Comment: I look forward to the rest of it :P

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify to this example:

```cpp
struct a {
    template <typename... Args>
    void va(Args...) {}

    template <typename X>
    void x(X) {}

    void y(int) {}
};

using no_args = void(a::*)();
using int_arg = void(a::*)(int);
```

And lets try the following four things:

```cpp
reinterpret_cast<no_args>(&MEMBER_FUNCTION);  // (1)
(no_args) &MEMBER_FUNCTION;  // (2)
(no_args) static_cast<int_arg>(&MEMBER_FUNCTION);  // (3)
int_arg temp = &MEMBER_FUNCTION; (no_args) temp;  // (4)
```

(Replacing `MEMBER_FUNCTION` with `&a::va<int>`, `&a::x<int>` and `&a::y`).

clang compiles all of them.
gcc compiles everything except (2) with `&a::va<int>` and `&a::x<int>`.
MSVC compiles everything except (1) and (2) with `&a::va<int>` (but is fine with `&a::x<int>`).

Notice that (3) is essentially the same as (4).

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a2qqyo showing an example of this.

What you can see from this is that `&MEMBER_FUNCTION` is not resolved to a specific member function pointer in case of templates, but if it is resolved, it is allowed to reinterpret it into another member function pointer type.

What the standard has to say:

[[over.over]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#1):

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set.
>   A function template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts.
>   A function with type F is selected for the function type FT of the target type required in the context if F (after possibly applying the function pointer conversion) is identical to FT.
>   [ Note: That is, the class of which the function is a member is ignored when matching a pointer-to-member-function type.
>   — end note
>    ]
>   The target can be:
>   [...]
>   - an explicit type conversion ([expr.type.conv], [expr.static.cast], [expr.cast])

An example given later on is:

```cpp
int f(double);
int f(int);
void g() {
  (int (*)(int))&f;             // cast expression as selector
}
```

And a few more quotes about templates:

[[temp.deduct.funcaddr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.funcaddr):

> Template arguments can be deduced from the type specified when taking the address of an overloaded function.
>   The function template's function type and the specified type are used as the types of P and A, and the deduction is done as described in [temp.deduct.type].

[[temp.arg.explicit]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#4)

> [...] if a template argument list is specified and it, along with any default template arguments, identifies a single function template specialization, then the template-id is an lvalue for the function template specialization.

This seems like MSVC is right.

`&a::va<int>` is not resolved unless you assign/cast it to a `void(a::*)(int)`. You should also be able to assign it to `void(a::*)(int, char)` or `void(a::*)(int, double, char)`, where the `Args` would be deduced as `{ int, char }` and `{ int, double, char }` respectively. That means that `(no_args) &a::va<int>` *should* fail, as there are many possible sets of `Args` it could be (All of them start with `int`, and clang overzealously resolves it), and none of them take zero parameters, so `(no_args) &a::va<int>` is a `static_cast` that should fail.

As for `&a::x<int>`, there is only one possible function, so it should work exactly the same way as `&a::y` (But gcc still hasn't resolved it yet).

Comment: Are you sure? Does any variadic template with template parameters specified means anything at least those parameters ? Doesnt va<int> mean simply va with Args = int and nothing more than that ?

Comment: @NN_ You can specify some of the template arguments, and the rest will be deduced (Which is why `templated_function<>` will work if you assign it to a pointer, and also that the rest of the parameter pack can't be deduced as empty yet in case it's assigned to a pointer where it isn't). [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/y324wK).

Comment: I see. Now the question why only clang allows conversion of variadic template function to function without arguments. https://godbolt.org/z/Racc05   

void test() {
    using F = void(\*)();
    using MF = void(a::\*)();
    F f = (F)freefunc<int>;
    MF mf = (MF)&a::memfunc<int, double>;
}

Comment: @NN_ I assume that clang mistakenly resolves `freefunc<int>` when inside a cast (As seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/QnqaEB), it creates `void freefunc(int);`). The other two don't do that, so they try to resolve the unresolved function as one with no args (Which fails). The clang compiler, when calling [`reinterpret_cast`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/0e0d37e253bc2b7a450d603dda71f8a3cf27ad24/lib/Sema/SemaCast.cpp#L2015) [tries to resolve templates](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/0e0d37e253bc2b7a450d603dda71f8a3cf27ad24/lib/Sema/SemaCast.cpp#L1988), but (continued)

Comment: @NN_ also resolves parameter packs completely there, which is why it can still be assigned with a longer parameter pack, but also can be cast.

Comment: So this is a bug in clang implementation and standard disallows such code or it can be implemented either way in compiler ?

Comment: Do you know why all compilers compile when you make a temporary variable ? ``auto q = &a<b>::va<int>; F f = (F)q;`` . Isn't it equivalent to the same code without  a temporary ? Immediately evaluated lambda also compiles well: ``F f = (F) ([]{return &a<b>::va<int>;}());``